# testing.postgresql can't locate initdb command, even when postgress is installed and running

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy
import testing.postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from app.config import Settings, mode
from databases import Database

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine
)

def get_database():
    if mode == 'prod':
        settings = Settings()
        db_config = {
            "drivername": "postgresql",
            "host": settings.DB_HOST,
            "username": settings.DB_USER,
            "password": settings.DB_PASSWORD,
            "port": settings.DB_PORT,
            "database": settings.DB_DATABASE
        }
        uri = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(**db_config)

        engine = create_engine(uri)
        Base = declarative_base()
        database = Database(str(engine.url))

        return engine, Base, database
    else:
        with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
            engine = create_engine(postgresql.url())
            Base = declarative_base()
            database = Database(str(engine.url))

            return engine, Base, database

engine, Base, database = get_database()
```

My code runs perfectly when `mode == 'prod'` but, when `mode == 'test'`, I get this error:

```
venv\lib\site-packages\testing\postgresql.py:144: in find_program
    raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
E   RuntimeError: command not found: initdb
```

I can say that progress is installed and running, and `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin` is in `PATH`.

I can't find what I can be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this trying to solve this issue myself. On macOS, I was able to fix this by initializing the locate db in a terminal with `sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp`. Run this and wait 10-15 minutes, and then restart the terminal and try `locate initdb`, it should return a list of locations. Then, make sure `psql` is in path with `which psql`, and even to be safe run `which initdb`. If all of these return locations, try your code again with a new terminal and it should work.